# How to add a local module as dependency to a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How can I add a module of a local project as dependency to another project?

I tried the following:

1. Add to `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app', ':module'
project(':module').projectDir = new File('/path/to/module')
```

2. Add to project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        ext { compileSdkVersion = 31; minSdkVersion = 19; targetSdkVersion = 31 }
    }
}
```

3. Add to app `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project (":module")
}
```

But this fails to build with error:

> Build file '/path/to/module/build.gradle' line: 3
>
> A problem occurred evaluating project ':module'.
> Plugin with id 'com.some.lib' not found.

I can build the module project without any issues with `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`, but how can I build it automatically as part of the parent project?

The goal is to develop the module and test the changes immediately in an example app.

The way I do it now is publish the module to local maven and let local maven override the dependency in the example app, but I wonder if there is a more direct way that automatically builds the module and where I can even debug-step through the module while testing it in the example app.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after colon `:` on line#2 in **settings.gradle**

It should be `project(':module')` but you have written `project(': module')`

Comment: That was a typo from copy/paste to SO, the actual code does not have that space.